# How to delete a file on s3 with: Meteor and aws-sdk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

From my Meteor app, I can upload an image on my s3 bucket and now I want to remove it. To do that, I'm using aws-sdk with:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk;
```

And this code:

```
  AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
        region: region
      });

  let s3 = new AWS.S3();

  let params = {
    Bucket: 'aaaa', // bucket 'name'
    Key: 'images/qqwd468767-9awdw' // 'path/imageKey'
   };

   console.log(params); // {Bucket: 'aaaa', Key: images/qqwd468767-9awdw }

   Meteor.wrapAsync(
     s3.deleteObject(params, function (error, data) {
       if (error) {
         console.log(error);
       } else {
         console.log(data);
       }
     })
   );
```

It's not working I get this error message :

```
TypeError: stream.setTimeout is not a function
    at features.constructor.handleRequest (modules.js?hash=4f9d58166294ad7d39d307939c58d106525401c5:178932)
    at executeSend (modules.js?hash=4f9d58166294ad7d39d307939c58d106525401c5:174057)
    at Request.SEND (modules.js?hash=4f9d58166294ad7d39d307939c58d106525401c5:174071)
    at Request.callListeners (modules.js?hash=4f9d58166294ad7d39d307939c58d106525401c5:173612)
    at Request.emit (modules.js?hash=4f9d58166294ad7d39d307939c58d106525401c5:173588)
    at Request.emit (modules.js?hash=4f9d58166294ad7d39d307939c58d106525401c5:175024)
    at Request.transition (modules.js?hash=4f9d58166294ad7d39d307939c58d106525401c5:174363)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (modules.js?hash=4f9d58166294ad7d39d307939c58d106525401c5:175171)
    at modules.js?hash=4f9d58166294ad7d39d307939c58d106525401c5:175183
    at Request.<anonymous> (modules.js?hash=4f9d58166294ad7d39d307939c58d106525401c5:174379)
```

I don't get if it's because of Meteor or my code. I tried to add in my CORS configuration : `<AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>` because it makes sense to allow delete, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this Meteor method to delete file

```
delete_s3: function(key) {
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: Meteor.settings.private.s3.AccessKey, secretAccessKey: Meteor.settings.private.s3.SecretKey, region: Meteor.settings.private.s3.region});
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
      Bucket: Meteor.settings.private.s3.bucket,
      Key: key
    };
    var deleteObject = Meteor.wrapAsync(s3.deleteObject(params, function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    }));   }
```